# svd out of sample vector projection

Tags: svd

Is it possible to project 'out of sample' vector into new space without using original data matrix? Given X (N * M) matrix, where N is number of vectors and M - number of features, we can decompose it into X = U * lambda * V_t, where U, V are orthogonals and lambda is diagonal.
By multiplying U * lambda we get original data projection in new space. How can I get these numbers for vector, which doesn't belongs to X?

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse me for not having a crisp idea of what you ask. You may be asking about the four fundamental projectors. An excellent presentation is  given in

Matrix Analysis for Scientists and Engineers

Alan Laub
ISBN 978-0-898715-76-7

Given a matrix **A** with *m* rows, *n* columns, and rank *rho* the matrix pseudoinverse is **A**<sup>+</sup>. We have an SVD

**A** = **U** **S** **V***

The domain matrices have the block partition in range and null space components

**U** = ( **U**<sub>R</sub> | **U**<sub>N</sub>)

**V** = ( **V**<sub>R</sub> | **V**<sub>N</sub>)

The invariant subspaces can be expressed in terms of spans of the column vectors of **U** and **V**.

Range of **A** = span( u<sub>1</sub>, u<sub>2</sub>, …, u<sub>rho</sub> )

Range of **A*** = span( v<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>2</sub>, …, v<sub>rho</sub> )

Null space of **A*** = span( u<sub>rho+1</sub>,  u<sub>rho+2</sub>,  …, u<sub>m</sub> )

Null space of **A** = span( v<sub>rho+1</sub>,  v<sub>rho+2</sub>,  …, v<sub>n</sub> )

The projections onto the invariant subspaces are these:

Projectors onto

Range space of **A**: **A****A**<sup>+</sup> = **U**<sub>R</sub>**U***<sub>R</sub> = sum[ u<sub>k</sub>u<sub>k</sub>*, ( k = 1, rho )]

Null space of **A***: **I**<sub>m</sub> - **A****A**<sup>+</sup> = **U**<sub>N</sub>**U***<sub>N</sub> = sum[ u<sub>k</sub>u<sub>k</sub>* ( k = rho + 1, m )]

Range space of **A***: **A**<sup>+</sup>**A** = **V**<sub>R</sub>**V***<sub>R</sub> = sum[ v<sub>k</sub>v*<sub>k</sub> ( k = 1, rho )]

Null space of **A**: **I**<sub>n</sub> - **A**<sup>+</sup>**A** = **V**<sub>N</sub>**V***<sub>N</sub> = sum[ v<sub>k</sub>v*<sub>k</sub> ( k = rho + 1, m )]

Just in case ...

You imply the identity **U** lambda = **A****V**. A companion is **V** lambda = **A*****U***.